# XMLHttpRequest in Awesomium

Tags: c#

i using Awesomium control in c#.net .i want send a request XMLHttpRequest in Awesomium control.

this is my code :

```
webControl1.Source = new Uri("http://example.com");
while (webControl1.IsLoading || !webControl1.IsLive)
Application.DoEvents();

var result = webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("(function() {var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
" xmlhttp.open('GET','http://example.com',false);" +
"xmlhttp.send();" +
 "return xmlhttp.responseText; })();");

MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

but ExecuteJavascriptWithResult returned undefined.